# Is there any good way to deal with singularities(when x=y) in numerical integration ？

Tags: numerical-methods, improper-integrals, singularity

The integral equation with a singularity is as follows:
$$\Omega=\int^\pi_0\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}}\,d\theta$$
I want to calculate this integral numerically. Is there an analytic expression that can be used when $\theta=0$, or is there a way to remove the singularity? Any insights on dealing with singular numerical integrals are very useful to me.

Thank you

Comment: The integral does not converge, and so cannot be computed. Are you instead trying to integral away from zero? e.g. $\int_{\epsilon}^{\pi}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$

Comment: Well，I did try to integrate from a smaller ϵ far away from 0, but the selection of the value of ϵ seems to have a great impact on the result of integration. There seems to be no standard for reference on how to select the appropriate ϵ.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the expansion of the integrand around $\theta=0$, you have
$$\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\theta }-\frac{11}{12 \sqrt{2}} \theta +O\left(\theta ^3\right)$$ which shows how you can remove the singularity.

$$\int_0^\pi \left(\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}} -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\theta }\right)\, d\theta=-\sqrt{2} (2+\log (\pi )-2\log (2))$$

**Edit**

$$\Omega(\epsilon)=\int^\pi_\epsilon\frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{1-\cos(\theta)}}\,d\theta=2\frac{ \sin \left(\frac{\epsilon }{2}\right) \log \left(\cot \left(\frac{\epsilon
   }{4}\right)\right)- \sin (\epsilon )}{\sqrt{1-\cos (\epsilon )}}$$ If you let $\epsilon=4 \tan ^{-1}(t)$
$$\Omega(t)=\sqrt{2} \left(2-\frac{4}{t^2+1}-\log (t)\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you use Taylor expansion for the first formula? How it was obtained is not easy to understand. In addition, in the second formula, the integral result after removing the singularity is -1.570986930. I think the negative value may be unreasonable

Comment: @runss. Yes for Taylor. IMHO, the remaining is correct.

Comment: Do you have any reference books or literature related to this question that you can recommend to me? I still don't know how to solve this integral.

Answer (score 1):

If $\theta$ is close to $0$, then $\cos \theta$ behaves like $1-\frac{\theta^2}{2}$. It means that the integrand behaves like $\frac{2-\theta^2}{\sqrt 2 \theta}$, hence the singularity in zero is non-integrable.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think this elliptic type Green's function kernel can be integrated when x = y. $\int^\pi_0\frac{cos(\theta)}{x^x+y^2-2xycos(\theta)}$